# Nginx proxy intercept redirect and pass custom redirect to client

Tags: nginx, redirect, proxy

I have a web application that wants to access files from a third party site without CORS enabled. The requests can be to an arbitrary domain with arbitrary parameters. I'm sending a request to my domain containing the target encoded as a GET parameter, i.e.

```
GET https://www.example.com/proxy/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fnginx.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2Fhttp%2Fngx_http_proxy_module.html
```

Then in Nginx I do

```
location /proxy/ {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    set_unescape_uri $dst $arg_url;
    proxy_pass $dst;
}
```

This works for single files, but the target server sometimes returns a Location header, which I want to intercept and modify for the client to retry.

Basically I would like to escape $sent_http_location, append it to https://www.example.com/proxy/?url= and pass that back to the browser to retry.

I've tried doing

```
set_escape_uri $tmp $sent_http_location;
proxy_redirect $sent_http_header /pass/?v=$tmp;
```

but this doesn't work. I've also tried saving the Location header, then ignoring the incoming header with

```
proxy_hide_header
```

and replacing it with my own

```
proxy_set_header
```

but ignoring causes me to lose the variable saving it.

How can I configure Nginx to accomplish this handling of redirects so that I could pass a encoded URL would be returned to the user when the proxied site redirects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several problems with your unsuccessful approach:

1. `proxy_set_header` sets the header that goes to the upstream server, not to the client. So even if `$sent_http_location` hadn't been empty, your configuration couldn't possibly work as you wanted it to.
2. `$sent_http_<header>` variables point exactly to the same area of memory as the response headers that will be send to the client. So when `proxy_hide_header` takes effect, the specified header is being removed from the memory along with the value of the corresponding `$sent_http_<header>`.
3. `set_escape_uri` works at a very early stage of the request processing, way before `proxy_pass` is called and the `Location` header is returned from the upstream server. So it will always process the at that time empty variable `$sent_http_location` and the result also will always be the empty variable.

The last problem is the most serious. The only way to make `set_escape_uri` work after `proxy_pass` is to force Nginx to leave the current location and start the processing all over again. This can be done with the `error_page` trick:

```
location /proxy/ {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    set_unescape_uri $dst $arg_url;
    proxy_pass $dst;

    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 301 = @rewrite_301;
}

location @rewrite_301 {
    set_escape_uri $location $upstream_http_location;
    return 301 /pass/?v=$location;
}
```

Note the use of `$upstream_http_location` instead of `$sent_http_location`. When Nginx leaves the context of the location, it assumes that the request will be proxied to another upstream, or processed in some other way, and so it clears the headers recieved from the last `proxy_pass`, to make room for new response headers.

Unlike `$sent_http_<header>` vairables, which represent response headers that will be send to the client, `$upstream_http_<header>` variables represent response headers that were recieved from the upstream. Because of that, they are only replaced with new values when the request is proxied to another upstream server. So, once set, these variables can be used at any moment, they will not be cleared.